# Проблемы со с компилироваными проектами Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Создал небольшой проект на `Visual Studio` 2015 Commynity, используя библиотеку `SFML`. Решил показать друзьям, отправил и им выходит **ошибка: Нет прав доступа**.
Кто знает как мне можно это исправить?

Comment: Без уточнения к чему нет прав доступа вообще ничего сказать конкретное не возможно. Да, и что это за библиотека SFML, объясните для чего она нужна, ссылку на нее дайте.

Comment: Может вы DLL им забыли дать нужные?